# The webpage cannot be found

Tags: c#-4.0

in my project i have an option where my application redirect to another website where i can make login but right now i am getting problem on IE only-

This error (HTTP 404 Not Found) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the website, but the page you wanted was not found. It's possible that the webpage is temporarily unavailable. Alternatively, the website might have changed or removed the webpage.

this problem is only in IE and it's working well in other browsers but once i will provide invalid useridor password then on IE also it's showing an error message that Invalid username or password but giving valid username and password it's showing above problem.
i have searched a lot in google but i didn't get any appropriate way to short the problem.
so anybody , help me.

Comment: You dont offer any details except that IE can't connect. How are you trying to connect? Is this web-based? Application-based?

Comment: it's a web based application.simply i used an iframe in my application and where inside that iframe i am using another websites url and that website is also open there and there is a login facility .when i enter valid  username and password then it should be redirect to another page but it's giving the above problem?